# refresh page in angular2 app

Tags: javascript, angular2-routing, angular5

I have two questions about refreshing page in angular2 app.
The first one is done after the user clickes F5.
I managed to find a solution to capture the user clicking F5 but I can't seem to capture this scenario but what I saw is that the previous history disappears because I see the document.location to the current page.

The second question is capturing the refresh button in the browser on an angular2 app.
I read a few people who also looked for a solution for that and saw that the solution was to use:
**onbeforeunload**

or

**onUnload**
but this doesn't seem to work.
Does angular has an out of the box handling for that?

Here are my routes:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent },
  {
    path: 'courses',
    component: CoursesListDetailsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'course/:id/steps',
    component: CourseStepsListComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'course/:id/subCourses',
    component: SubCoursesListComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'step/:id',
    component: StepComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'course/:id/description',
    component: CourseDescriptionComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: It's not fully clear, please clarify, what do you want to handle by this capturing? Do you need to catch any page reloading or what?

Comment: what you want to achieve on refresh? because on refresh the route will refresh and execute the code mentioned in controller pointed on the route.

Comment: What I want to achieve is a refresh of the current page (component).
When I refresh the page, I'm directed to the login page component which has the route:
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent }
I added my routes configuration

Comment: Angular will not help in that case. I had the same challenge in my project. The only way to solve it is to use one of the clients save techs. Like cookies, session storage ..... and in your login guard, you try to read the value from where you saved it if it exists then you return true and allow him to go further, when not then he has to login again.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm doing so far when the user clicks F5. I have a dataService that I use to keep track of the last page the user was in before he clicked F5.
Maybe I should open a feature request...

Comment: you can store it in session storage and in that way, you will guarantee that your data will not be lost on refresh.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm doing so far.
Thanks